# Docker keeps restarting without error on logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a simple instance using docker-compose with this simple yml(It's a Laravel project, but right now i'm not initializing anything):

```
version: '3'

services:
    api:
        image: amazonlinux
        container_name: test-backend
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
```

Here i'm just trying to create an AmazonLinux instance to test some libraries i'm installing to let the backend run, but for some reason, when i make docker-compose up, the instance keeps restarting. I tried checking the logs, but they are empty, there is no error message, warning, or anything that tells me what is happening.

[image: log]

I tried running the instance manually with `docker run -dit amazonlinux:latest` and that works, create an instance with AmazonLinux that doesn't restart, but the compose one keeps doint it. I have also tried wiping everything with

```
- docker rm $(docker ps -aq) -f
- docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q) -f
- docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

Yet keeps happening, i restarted Docker, still happens. Other instances of other projects don't have any problem, they can be launched with docker-compose up, it's just this one the one causing a problem, Does someone know what i might be doing wrong? As an aditional detail, i believe this started happening after i made an accidental ctrl+c in the middle of a docker-compose up, but i'm not sure if that might be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not giving your container anything to do.

If you `docker image inspect amazonlinux`, you can see that the default behavior of the image is to start an interactive `bash` shell:

```
[...]
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"/bin/bash\"]"
            ],
[...]
```

When you start a container via `docker-compose up`, this is similar to running `docker run <containername>`: by default, the container is not attached to stdin and does not allocate a tty.  When `bash` is run in this environment, it's default behavior is to exit immediately. You can simulate this yourself by running:

```
bash < /dev/null
```

This is why you container keeps restarting: it starts up, `bash` attempts to run an interactive shell but it can't, so it exits.

---

The solution here is to run something besides `bash`. What are you trying to do with this container? You would typically run some sort of service (like a web server, or a database server, or a message broker, or...etc).  Set an appropriate `command` key in the service in your `docker-compose.yml`.

If you're really just playing around, a good option is `sleep inf`, which means "do nothing, forever". This will allow the container to start and keep running, and you can then use `docker-compose exec` to run commands inside wthe container:

```
version: '3'

services:
    api:
        image: amazonlinux
        container_name: test-backend
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
        command:
            - sleep
            - inf
```